# How are backlit aircraft panels (for simulators) made?

Tags: flight-simulator

I'm wondering by **which method this sort of aircraft panel that enabling backlighting are made?** What is the process? I've gathered they are acrylic but how is the gray paint selectively removed?

[pic http://www.simparts.de/WebRoot/Store/Shops/15465782/4B72/6E37/0BF8/50E9/641B/C0A8/28BA/29AA/A320-OHP-009-5.jpg](http://www.simparts.de/WebRoot/Store/Shops/15465782/4B72/6E37/0BF8/50E9/641B/C0A8/28BA/29AA/A320-OHP-009-5.jpg)

Comment: Possibly laser etching? Great question btw, looking forward to seeing the answer.

Comment: @DannyBeckett  i was hoping you might have the answer to this one :/

Comment: Missed the "backlit" part in the title... I guess it's not laser then, I don't know the answer, I've only just started building mine... it just consists of a few switches so far!

Comment: same way other backlit panels are made perhaps?

Comment: Wipers?  Must be a fancy airplane :)  And I believe lasters are often used to remove that kind of stuff.

Comment: Heheh, rain repellant sounds like a force field.

Answer (score 3):

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKhq8vWqcR4) says the following:

> Here's my Tonson TS-3040C CNC making an EFIS panel for my flight
>   simulator. For the lettering I am using a 0.4mm End Mill and for
>   cutting out I'm using a 1mm End Mill. RPM is 10000 and movement is
>   300mm / Min. **The material is Cast Acrylic which I have given one coat
>   of black paint and two coats of grey paint.**

So that's at least one method, but there are probably more...

Answer (score 3):

It's a 3 layer color system with white opaque special laser colour, a black light block layer, and the final colour. For military it stays black without the 3rd one. After spray painting the special laser color is removed with a laser system. You can see it [here](http://youtu.be/-g4lvXXOQME?t=1m2s).

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.mikesflightdeck.com/pedestal/panels__lighting.html) has some good information and a graphic, looks like the same as shown in the video Manfred posted. Clear plastic with an opaque layer that is engraved off, and lighted from beneath.