# DIY switch panel

Tags: flight-simulator

I'm looking to build a switch panel as a present for a friend who's found of flight simulation games.

The coding and interface to the computer is no issue, but I'm completely unaware of how an airplane is piloted, hence I have now idea which are the most used/important/common across all planes switchs that I should put on the panel.

To be complete, the panel should be composed of only buttons and switches, no potentio-meters and certainly not sim>hardware interfaces as those would involve too much money/time in the making.

My friend already possess a joystick and a gas thing (like to control the engine rpm I guess ?).

Thanks to anyone that can enlighten me =)

EDIT (on-hold status) :
I know how this will end but let's try at least. Can someone explicitly tell me how I'm off-topic ? To use the words from the very help page, I think my question is quite on point for **aviation enthusiasts** willing to know what instruments in a cockpit are important besides the stick/yoke and throttles. Moreover this doesn't fall into the explicit list of off-topics. I already got the answer I was looking for, so you can delete this post as you wish, potentially denying other people knowledge. [Here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2608/how-are-backlit-aircraft-panels-for-simulators-made?rq=1) is, for example, a guy asking about a painting process on panels. This is useful information.

Comment: Start with the basics and make "unrealistic" but practical panels at first. As your skills improve, along with your familiarity, you can advance to more realistic and/or complicated panels. I'd start off by basically copying these: http://www.saitek.com/uk/prod/switch.html , http://www.saitek.com/uk/prod/radio.html , http://www.saitek.com/uk/prod/multi.html

Comment: @SnakeDoc Alright mate, thanks for the quick reply. Looks like the first panel (switch) would be the easiest to make. I understand all of these are switches except the off/r/l/both/start and the gear up/down : are those behaving like discrete positions or more like a potentiometer (ie : does it mean something to be halfway between say "OFF" and "R", same for the gear thing )

Comment: For the engine starter (the off/r/l/both/start) switch, it's usually a multi-position rotary switch. You only need 5 positions, so you can just ignore (or not wire) the positions you aren't needing. To "feel" more authentic, it should probably click into position (so that the user knows it moved... there's no such thing as sort-of-on for ignition systems). Regarding the landing gear, you can get by with a simple toggle switch here. Gear is either down or up. I'd suggest taking a "joy" ride through the simulator, paying attention to what switches what, and when etc :)

Comment: Aircraft bone yards often sell parts like this for simulator use. [You can get the real thing if you look around.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5BmA3ejyHY)

Comment: @SnakeDoc Wow thanks for the feedback mate, I think I'll have the gear up/down as a simple switch, maybe I'll go fancy and buy one of those switch with a covering red cap on top lol. As for the ignition system knob, this one might be tricky to find but I'll try.

Comment: @Dave Wow that guy ain't messing around with a whole plane head in his garage lol ! I like my buddy but not to that point I'm afraid =)

Comment: Rotary switches are easy enough to some by. Getting a switch cover that you like might be another story ;-P Here's one for example: https://www.amazon.com/Plastic-Position-Channel-Rotary-Switch/dp/B00DUYQJWQ

Comment: Good luck. Sim'ing is a lot of fun, and making your own gear is even more-so!

Comment: Alright guys, thanks for the feedback, to my surprise I found cheap 5 position rotary switches quite easily so that's good.
I'll post final product here once I get all the parts, cheers =)

Comment: One final question though, in flight simulators (I think my friend use flight simulator 10 but not sure) is a switch, let say beacon on/off, bound to a single toogle key ? Like do you bind say 'J' for 'toogle beacon on/off' or do you have to bind say 'J' : Beacon ON and 'K' : Beacon OFF ? I'm asking this because I'm pre-coding most of it so once I get the parts it's already ready to go =)

Comment: In FSX, most of the keys act ON/OFF (e.g. G for gear UP/DOWN)/ Some are used differently, e.g. flaps retract/extend (F6/F7). But anyway everything can be customized. See default [key bindings](http://stridspilot.se/files/FSX_KeyCommands.pdf.)

Comment: About your edit, as you can see I have not voted, but I understand those who did. Also, only 3 of the voters selected it, the other two probably voted as "too broad". The problem here is that you are not giving us any kind of technical detail, and an answer should cover all possible aspects of all possible combinations of switches you might need. As for the "aviation enthusiast" side of your point, we refer generally to people interested to the elements of aviation, and hobby-ism (including RC and simulators) has not generally being considered within our scope.

Comment: Adding to Federico, the problem is the scope is not limited (too broad) and actually seems to change when additional knowledge is provided, ending in the discussion format which the stack is not for. This is enough to trigger the closure (as you see I didn't either vote to close, but I could have). While you triggered interest, it could be more convenient to use the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=aviation.stackexchange.com) format. Why not try to start a room for this topic?

Comment: Alright I'd like to thank **Federico** and **mins** for at least giving me explicit reasons. I disagree with what you said as for me, asking "what are the essential switchs a cockpit should have" doesn't seem to be too broad or subject to change. Indeed in the comments I allowed myself to add another question about sim key binding but I do think that's what comments are for. Again, I might be wrong, I come from Math stack where trust me people are absolutely strict about off topic, but maybe I'm missing subtleties specific to Aviation stack. Still, thanks to both of you.

Comment: As mins said, I encourage you to pass by chat, we could work on a way to save the question :)

Comment: Since you want further clarification on why explaining the essential switches is "too broad", take a look at all the differences in these cockpits.  Explaining the differences would take a very lengthy discussion of avionics: http://aviationbookreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/glider-cockpit-2.jpg http://www.cap-ny153.org/Cockpit%20Cessna%20C172%20Instrument%20Panel.jpg http://www.twomoreweeks.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/F-16-Cockpit-2.jpg http://www.gulfstream.com/assets/images/_500/img19-zoom.jpg